# Combine two networks with if-else

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have two networks `ModelUp` and `ModelDown` which take the same inputs `x1, x2` where `x1` is 10 features and `x2` is a single number for each sample. I want a `combinedModel` network that does:

```
if x2>=1:
    return ModelUp([x1,x2])
else:
    return ModelDown([x1,x2])
```

There should be no training required for `combinedModel` once `ModelUp` and `ModelDown` have individually been trained.

How can I do this combination in `tensorflow.keras` (tensorflow version is `1.12.0`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would be an option. You need to check if it works for your use case.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def combineModels(ModelUp, ModelDown):
    input1 = Input(shape=(10,))
    input2 = Input(shape=(1,))
    # 
    selectModel1 = K.cast(K.greater_equal(input2, 1), dtype='float32')
    selectModel2 = K.cast(K.less(input2, 1), dtype='float32')
    # 
    out   = ModelUp([input1,input2]) * selectModel1 + ModelDown([input1,input2]) * selectModel2
    model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=out)
    return model

combinedModel = combineModels(ModelUp, ModelDown)
```

For Tensorflow 1:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Multiply, Add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def combineModels(ModelUp, ModelDown):
    input1       = Input(shape=(10,))
    input2       = Input(shape=(1,))
    # 
    selectModel1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.greater_equal(x, K.constant(1.)))    (input2)
    selectModel2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.less(x, K.constant(1.)))(input2)
    # 
    selectModel1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(x, dtype='float32'))(selectModel1)
    selectModel2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(x, dtype='float32'))(selectModel2)
    # 
    out1 = Multiply()([ModelUp([input1,input2]), selectModel1])
    out2 = Multiply()([ModelDown([input1,input2]), selectModel2])
    out  = Add()([out1, out2])
    model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=out)
    return model

combinedModel = combineModels(ModelUp, ModelDown)
```

Comment: Hi Max, I had to change it to `Input(shape=(10,),)` but I still get the error: ```ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("add:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
``` at the final step of creating the Model.

Comment: Hi. Okay, sorry, this might be an issue related to Tensorflow 1 (I do not have this exact version you have so I cannot reproduce. You can try to use the second solution I added above, it is using layers throughout. Generally, I would recommend to switch to Tensorflow 2 though.

Comment: Hey thanks with the `Lambda` layer it doesn't crash on TF1 (which I'm stuck using for legacy reasons). I'll mark as solved once I verify that it's doing what I want it to do.